# pass shared_ptr to std::bind through std::ref will strip it's polymorphism

Tags: c++, templates, bind, ref, dynamic-cast

My program crashed by SIGSEGV when I try to dynamic_cast a Base class "this" pointer to a Derived class pointer. I am wondering if it has anything to do with std::bind and std::ref. Below is my example code which can produce the problem.

```
// header h.hpp

#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template <typename T> 
class Derived;

class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() {}

  template <typename T> 
  void foo(const T &t) {
    cout << "Base foo\n";
    auto derived = dynamic_cast<Derived<T> *>(this); // SIGSEGV crash!
    derived->foo(t);
  }

private:
};

template <typename T> 
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  void foo(const T &t) { cout << "Derived foo\n"; }

private:
};

class Outter {
public:
  void init();
  void run();

private:
  void run_foo(shared_ptr<Base> &base);

  class Inner {
  public:
    void run() {
      for (const auto &f : foos_) {
        f();
      }
    }

    void set_foo(function<void()> f) { 
        foos_.push_back(f); 
    }

  private:
    static vector<function<void()>> foos_;
  };

  Inner inner_;
  vector<shared_ptr<Base>> bases_;
};
```

```
// source main.cpp

#include "h.hpp"

vector<function<void()>> Outter::Inner::foos_;

void Outter::init() {
  shared_ptr<Base> base = make_shared<Derived<int>>();
  bases_.push_back(base);
  
//   inner_.set_foo(bind(&Outter::run_foo, this, base)); // no ref version
  inner_.set_foo(bind(&Outter::run_foo, this, ref(base))); // ref verison
}

void Outter::run() { inner_.run(); }

void Outter::run_foo(shared_ptr<Base> &base) {
  int t = 123;
  base->foo(t);
}

int main() {
  Outter outter;
  outter.init();
  outter.run();
  return 0;
}
```

If I commented out the ref version and use the "no-ref" version, the program runs fine and won't break. It seems like the std::ref function is chopping the polymorphism off of the Base shared_ptr, why is that so?

Comment: `base` goes out of scope at the end of `init`, so the reference that the bind object holds to it is left dangling.  Use `ref(bases_.back())` if you really need a reference, but I see no reason to use one in this case.

Comment: a reference to a `shared_ptr` doesn't make a lot of sense, just pass by value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1387438 https://youtu.be/4NYC-VU-svE

Comment: If you can upgrade to C++11 or later, you can use lambdas rather than `bind`.

Comment: BTW what this code suppose to do? Looks like you made this over complicated. This `template <typename T> void foo(const T &t)` is weird complicated and fragile. If you describe your goal we can provide better solution then this.

Comment: "My program crashed by SIGSEGV" - So obviously you tried to access some memory that was outside the address space allocated to your program (that's what a segmentation fault means).

Comment: Side note: `// header h.hpp` ... `using namespace std;` - No. Don't ever do that. [using namespace std; is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) in a source file - but in a *header* it's a disaster. Please stop doing that.

Comment: @Eljay `std::bind()` was introduced in C++11 alongside `std::function` and lambdas

Comment: @MarekR Yes this is history code by someone else, I'm dealing with the whole project's objects' lifetime issue and exit routine, so for now I don't have intention for changing the architecture bit yet, but thanks anyway

Comment: @JesperJuhl yea I just use it for convenient for this demo, please don't worry

Comment: @Komgcn it doesn't matter who is the author of this code. The sooner you will try to fix it the better (less pain in future). I suspect you need double dispatch or visitor pattern to make this code less buggy and more maintainable. To be sure explanation of intended logic is needed and possible ranges of types for `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to do with `shared_ptr` or polymorphism, your `shared_ptr<Base> base` simply goes out of scope.

Consider this example:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<int>& ptr)
{
    std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void()> f;
    std::shared_ptr<int> backup;
    {
        std::shared_ptr<int> ptr{new int{7}};
        backup = ptr;
        f = std::bind(foo, std::ref(ptr));
        // f = std::bind(foo, ptr);
    }
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

If you use `std::ref`, calling `f();` will have undefined behaviour, because `ptr` is out of scope and `foo` has a dangling reference, regardless of the fact that the integer it managed is still shared with another shared_ptr still in the scope.

[example with addr sanitizer](https://godbolt.org/z/KKGT8qYvP)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Indeed, what was I thinking..hahaXD

Answer (score 3):

You have basic dangling reference undefined behavior.

Here:

```cpp
void Outter::init() {
  shared_ptr<Base> base = make_shared<Derived<int>>();
  bases_.push_back(base);
  
//   inner_.set_foo(bind(&Outter::run_foo, this, base)); // no ref version
  inner_.set_foo(bind(&Outter::run_foo, this, ref(base))); // ref verison
}
```

when this function ends lifetime of local variable `base` ends.
This means that `foos_` contains and `std::function` which uses reference to object which lifetime ended.

Main problem is:

```cpp
void Outter::run_foo(shared_ptr<Base> &base)
```

Why you need here reference to smart a pointer?
This function doesn't do any kind of ownership transfer for its arguments, so proper API for it should use, raw pointer to `Base` or reference to `Base` (depending on your coding convention):

```cpp
void Outter::run_foo(Base* base)
```

After that there are two ways to fix it:

- if you can provide warranty on lifetime of object pointed by `base`, you can just use raw pointer:

```cpp
inner_.set_foo(bind(&Outter::run_foo, this, base.get()));
```

- drop use of `std::bind` and use lambda:

```cpp
inner_.set_foo([this, base]() { run_foo(base.get()); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yea I definitely had a pointer dangling problem. Regarding why the codes look like this, it is codes in other work groups and I guess I will leave them with it beside solving my problem